# Dataframe count set of conditions passed by several columns on a per row basis

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks something like this:

```
date   A_1  A_2  A_3  B_1  B_2  B_3  C_1  C_2  C_3  D_1  D_2  D_3
xxx    4    5    6    2    3    1    5    7    2    4    3    1
xxx    3    3    2    4    5    2    6    2    3    2    4    2
xxx    5    7    5    1    3    3    4    5    4    8    2    2
xxx    6    1    8    6    1    4    1    2    7    4    3    5
```

I am trying to compute a value based on a condition for every row which will apply across the column groupings of A, B, C, D, etc. and count how many of those groups passed the condition, for example, some pseudo-code:

```
count = 0
for each (A, B, C, D) as col:
    if col_1 > 3 and (col_2 > col_3):
        count++

dataframe['count'] = count
```

Expected output:

```
date   A_1  A_2  A_3  B_1  B_2  B_3  C_1  C_2  C_3  D_1  D_2  D_3  count
xxx    4    5    6    2    3    1    5    7    2    4    3    1    2
xxx    3    3    2    4    5    2    6    2    3    2    4    2    1
xxx    5    7    5    1    3    3    4    5    4    8    2    2    2
xxx    6    1    8    6    1    4    1    2    7    4    3    5    0
```

This would mean the example dataframe would end up with a new column with a value of 2 because in this example column C and D pass the set of conditions.

Later I plan to do something for each row with a count value above some number.

The best way I was able to come up with looked something like this:

```py
for col in cols:
    conditions.append(
        (
            (dataframe[f'{col}_1'] > min_corr_coef) & 
            (dataframe[f'{col}_2'] < (dataframe[f'{col_3}])
        ) | 
        (dataframe[f'{col}_1'] <= min_corr_coef)
    )

conditions.append(
    (dataframe[dataframe.loc[:,cols] > min_corr_coef].count(axis=1) >= min_corr_pair)
)

if conditions:
    dataframe.loc[
        reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, conditions),
        'pass'] = 1
```

Not only is this incorrect, but it is also extremely slow. What I like about it, is that it is readable and adding additional conditions if there are more columns/different data is relatively straightforward.

I am not sure if this type of operation is too complex to perform on a dataframe the way I am trying to and perhaps I need to change my data structure or not, but I figured I'd see if there is some way of going about this before I start to re-write things.

Ideally the logic being applied to the column groups (A, B, C, D in this case) can be modular and whatever method I use to do this should be easy to add/remove conditions because I want to be able to add/remove data columns and logic conditions over time.

What I am trying to do is test an arbitrary set of conditions when one of the columns for a group (which is a correlation coefficient) is above a certain value. If enough of the column groups pass the conditions, do something.

Thanks in advance, I am a python and pandas novice and this has been giving me a headache for days.

Comment: kindly add the expected output

Comment: **Use `.iloc[]` slicing**, if it's guaranteed that the column names occur in regular groups of three named `X_1, X_2, X_3`. then you can use `apply(..., axis=1)` to run your function on each subslice of three columns. Then the rest is a list-comprehension, and `.sum()`. No need for iteration. But please post more lines of input.

Comment: About the performance of your approach: don't do stuff iteratively; learn how to use vectorized commands like `apply(, axis=1)`, `.sum(..., axis=1)` etc. Learn how to use slicing with `.iloc[]` / `.loc[]`. Don't iteratively append stuff, least of all subexpressions. Don't use `reduce()`, it's base Python not pandas, it doesn't vectorize. Don't generate temporaries, if avoidable. Please skim the tutorial [*10 minutes to pandas*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html).

Comment: @smci - not guaranteed the column groups will be in groups of 3

Comment: @sammywemmy - edited

Comment: Then edit the example data to give a specific idea; just saying "I want to execute arbitrary functions on arbtirary slices of arbitrarily-named columns in a df" isn't saying much. For example if you only want to read the columns named 'B_', you could use `df.filter(regex=r'^B_', axis=1)`. But if you want to write them too, you'll need `.loc/.iloc[]` with ranges of indices, like I show.

Comment: What does *"later, do something for each row with a count > threshold"* mean? A computation that only reads it? or writes it? or aggregates it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's ignore `date` and handle the other columns first.

Remove date, create a MultiIndex using [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split), and [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas-dataframe-stack) to long form:

```
new_df = df.drop(columns='date')
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
new_df = new_df.stack(level=0)
```

```
     1  2  3
0 A  4  5  6
  B  2  3  1
  C  5  7  2
  D  4  3  1
1 A  3  3  2
  B  4  5  2
  C  6  2  3
  D  2  4  2
2 A  5  7  5
  B  1  3  3
  C  4  5  4
  D  8  2  2
3 A  6  1  8
  B  6  1  4
  C  1  2  7
  D  4  3  5
```

Apply the condition row-wise:

```
new_df['condition'] = new_df['1'].gt(3) & new_df['2'].gt(new_df['3'])
```

Then [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html#pandas-series-sum) level 0 and assign back to the original `df`:

```
df['count'] = new_df['condition'].sum(level=0)
```

(Alternatively sum the conditions directly rather than assigning to both `new_df` and `df`)

```
df['count'] = (new_df['1'].gt(3) & new_df['2'].gt(new_df['3'])).sum(level=0)
```

`df`:

```
  date  A_1  A_2  A_3  B_1  B_2  B_3  C_1  C_2  C_3  D_1  D_2  D_3  count
0  xxx    4    5    6    2    3    1    5    7    2    4    3    1      2
1  xxx    3    3    2    4    5    2    6    2    3    2    4    2      1
2  xxx    5    7    5    1    3    3    4    5    4    8    2    2      2
3  xxx    6    1    8    6    1    4    1    2    7    4    3    5      0
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx'], 'A_1': [4, 3, 5, 6],
    'A_2': [5, 3, 7, 1], 'A_3': [6, 2, 5, 8],
    'B_1': [2, 4, 1, 6], 'B_2': [3, 5, 3, 1],
    'B_3': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'C_1': [5, 6, 4, 1],
    'C_2': [7, 2, 5, 2], 'C_3': [2, 3, 4, 7],
    'D_1': [4, 2, 8, 4], 'D_2': [3, 4, 2, 3],
    'D_3': [1, 2, 2, 5]
})

new_df = df.drop(columns='date')
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
new_df = new_df.stack(level=0)
new_df['condition'] = new_df['1'].gt(3) & new_df['2'].gt(new_df['3'])
df['count'] = new_df['condition'].sum(level=0)
print(df)
```

Comment: This seems to work great!  Having a working proof of concept to work with now is a lot farther along than I was! Thank you so much!

Comment: @WerkkreW: converting your dataframe wide-to-long is not scaleable or performant on large dataframes; better to figure out how to slice it with `.loc/.iloc[]`

Answer (score 1):

Solution as one-liner:

```
>>> sum(df1.iloc[:, range(3*i,3*(i+1))].apply(lambda x: x[0] > 3 and (x[1] > x[2]), axis=1) for i in range(len(df1.columns)//3)).tolist()

[2]
```

Approach: **Use `.iloc[]` slicing**, if it's guaranteed that the column names occur in regular groups of three named `X_1, X_2, X_3`:

```
for i in range(len(df.columns)//3):
    df.iloc[:, range(3*i,3*(i+1))]
  
      A_1  A_2  A_3
date               
xxx     4    5    6
      B_1  B_2  B_3
date               
xxx     2    3    1
      C_1  C_2  C_3
date               
xxx     5    7    2
      D_1  D_2  D_3
date               
xxx     4    3    1
```

Then you can `apply(..., axis=1)` whatever lamba function or custom function you want on each slice of three columns:

```
for i in range(len(df1.columns)//3):
    # Your commands go here, print()ing just as an example
    print(df1.iloc[:, range(3*i,3*(i+1))])
    print(df1.iloc[:, range(3*i,3*(i+1))].apply(lambda x: x[0] > 3 and (x[1] > x[2]), axis=1))

      A_1  A_2  A_3
date               
xxx     4    5    6
date
xxx    False
dtype: bool
      B_1  B_2  B_3
date               
xxx     2    3    1
date
xxx    False
dtype: bool
      C_1  C_2  C_3
date               
xxx     5    7    2
date
xxx    True
dtype: bool
      D_1  D_2  D_3
date               
xxx     4    3    1
date
xxx    True
dtype: bool
```

Now you can `apply()` across each column-slice-of-three-columns, and then `sum()` vertically, or whatever you want (instead of for-loop with increment.)

Comment: Columns wont always be 3.  To add detail, the idea I am working with is that there will always be at least 1 column per item for the price correlation coefficient, and then some arbritray # of additional columns of data where I want to be able to perform arbitrary logic operations across. So group A might be 3 columns, or 9, or 15, and the forumlae I want to use to evaluate the condition should be relatively easy to modify.

Comment: The above said, I am trying to look at your answer and see if I can make sense of it to use in my code!